# More than one colour in text field (AS3)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Is there any way that I can change the colour of everything before the colon?

My code is this and the colon is on the 11th line.

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;

joinBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, joinRoomClick);
function joinRoomClick(event:MouseEvent){
    outputTxt.text = "Welcome to chat room" + " " + roomTxt.text + "! You're the only person here!";
} 

function sendMessage(event:MouseEvent){
    if(userTxt.length > 0 && inputTxt.length > 0){
        outputTxt.text += "\n" + "" + "\n" + userTxt.text + ": " + inputTxt.text;
        userTxt.text = "";
        inputTxt.text = "";
    }
}
```

So I want the subjective text before the colon to be the HEX #047B7B.

Any way to do this?

Comment: use one label and add the text before colon and add color property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can have multiple colors in one text field:

```
var textFormat1:TextFormat = textField.getTextFormat(0, 10);
textFormat1.color = 0x0000ff;
textField.setTextFormat(textFormat1, 0, 10);


var textFormat2:TextFormat = textField.getTextFormat(11, 20);
textFormat2.color = 0x00ff00;
textField.setTextFormat(textFormat2, 11, 20);
```

You just need to adjust the indexes (0-10; 11-20), depending on where your colon is (use `indexOf` in order to find it).

Comment: Where would I put all this?

Comment: Well wherever you set the text. Basically, if your text field has the appropriate color, you just need one of those in order to set the proper color for the text before colon (starting from index 0, continuing to index text.indexOf(':'))